# How to set file type for files without any type

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In a directory, there are some files without a file type. So they don't have a `.xxx`, I know their type and I want to set that.

How can I get their list and add their type, for example `.srt`?

I can get a list of all files with a file type, with the following command:

```
Ls * | ? {$_.name -match '\.\w{3}$' } | FT
```

But, still the following command doesn't give the desired result:

```
Ls * | ? {$_.name -match '[^\.\w{3}]$' } | FT
```

Also, I need some help with renaming them and adding their type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the extension of all the files in a folder without an extension to `.srt` you can use `Rename-Item` from the pipeline like this

**Please be careful, this will change the extension of** ***ALL*** **files without an extension in the directory you choose to .srt**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Path\To\Files | Where-Object -FilterScript {-not $_.Extension} | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.FullName + ".srt") }
```

Explanation of this pipeline below

Get all files

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Path\To\Files
```

Where the file doesnt have an extension

```
Where-Object -FilterScript {-not $_.Extension}
```

For each file in the directory

```
ForEach-Object { }
```

Rename the Item to what it was called before ($_.FullName) + the extension of our choice (.srt)

```
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.FullName + ".srt")
```

Comment: So we have an `Extension` property as well! I was trying to get that by regular expressions! I was obsessed with regular expressions and was trying to set the file extension with them too, but string concatenation does the job.

Comment: If you every want to find out what properties are available on an object you can use `Get-Member`, to find out what other properties you can use for files you could run `Get-ChildItem | Get-Member`